# How to check app is open or not in android

Tags: android

I want when a user clicked on the notification, if the app is open, open Activity1. else if the app is closed and destroyed, open Activity2.
I write this method in my Service(receive and create notifications):

```
private boolean isAppRunning() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (procInfos != null) {
        for (final ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : procInfos) {
            if (processInfo.processName.equals("package name")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Intent notificationIntent;

        if (isAppRunning()) {
            notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity1.class);
        } else {
            notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", "I am from Notification");
            notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder sNotifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext(), offerChannelId);
        sNotifBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

But is not working and always open Activity1. Can you help me?

Comment: When service is running in the background, `isAppRunning` will always return `true`. To handle your use-case, I have a different approach

Comment: I have used the idea of SharedPreference to satisfy your requirements. Since we are storing in preference, data will get persisted even if the application is killed. I have persisted the application's running status. Please try it out and accept the answer if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inherit the below BaseActivity with all the activity in the application

BaseActivity.kt

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     private val preferences: SharedPreferences by lazy {
         PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
     }

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          preferences.isApplicationRunning = true
     }

     override fun onDestroy() {
         preferences.isApplicationRunning = false
         super.onDestroy()
     }

}
```

SharedPreferenceExt.kt

```
var SharedPreferences.isApplicationRunning: Boolean
set(value) {
    edit {
        putBoolean("APPLICATION_RUNNING", value)
    }
}
get() = getBoolean("APPLICATION_RUNNING", false)
```

your_service.kt

```
class YourService : Service() {

private val preferences: SharedPreferences by lazy {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
}

//below is the snippet of yours. changed the condition alone
private fun openActivity() {       
        if (preferences.isApplicationRunning) {
            notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity1.class);
        } else {
            notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", "I am from Notification");
            notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder sNotifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext(), offerChannelId);
        sNotifBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
       }
}
```

Comment: this is a good idea, thanks. But there is a problem. Suppose a notification is sent while the program is open but the user doesn't click on this, close the app and now click on the notification. SharedPreferences return true but the app is closed! I mean clear?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for if your app is in foreground or not. If this is the case, you need to register `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` in your application class and keep a track of `onActivityStarted` and `onActivityStopped`. If any of your activity is in started state means your app is in foreground.

Or in case you want to know if the app is completely closed in that case, it seems there is no sure shot way. Keeping a track of `onActivityDestroyed` is not recommended.

There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away as mentioned in doc. [Link To Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)